# Trivial Inheritance with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, superclass

```
function StringStream() {}
StringStream.prototype = new Array();
StringStream.prototype.toString = function(){ return this.join(''); };
```

Calling `new StringStream(1,2,3)` gives an empty array

```
x = new StringStream(1,2,3)
```

gives

```
StringStream[0]
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Can someone please explain why the superclass' (`Array`) constructor is not called?

Comment: who gave you this code and why ? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because `StringStream.prototype` is an array, the `StringStream` constructor is not replaced with `Array` as well.

You should implement that yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/gBrtf/.

```
function StringStream() {
    // push arguments as elements to this instance
    Array.prototype.push.apply(this, arguments);
}

StringStream.prototype = new Array;

StringStream.prototype.toString = function(){
    return this.join('');
};
```

Comment: So there is no way to call the constructor of Array obj and passing the arguments instead of invoking the push method?

Comment: @Markos Evlogimenos: You cannot combine `new` and `.apply` so I guess there is no way. Anyway, why are you trying to create a constructor that is equivalent to `Array`?